# Deriving a formula for velocity from the Lagrangian formula for generalized momentum

Tags: partial-derivative

On pg. 96 of *No-Nonsense Classical Mechanics*, the author asserts:

> [image]

The trouble I am having is with the highlighted portions.  In particular, how do we derive a *general* formula for velocity $\dot{q}$:

$$
\dot{q} = \dot{q}(q, p)
$$

from the formula for "generalized momentum" in the Lagrangian setting:

$$
p = \frac{\partial L } { \partial \dot{q} }
$$

?

Comment: I guess it means that $p = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} = f(q,\dot{q},t)$. Then we may try to express $\dot{q} = g(p,q,t)$.

Comment: Is there a way to determine what $g$ is in general?